# Java - Parsing a JLabel to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I'm simply trying to parse a string in  JLabel to a date using a `simpleDateFormatter()`.  Based On everything I've searched online, this code should work. However, I'm receiving the "cannot find symbol - method parse(java.lang.String)" error during compiliation.  Any advice on how to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated.

The JLabel in question was populated with a date from a database query using JDBC.

Additionally, I'm aware that that java.util.Date has been deprecated, but would still like to use it for this.

Code Snippet:

```
private Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
private JLabel dateDataLabel = new JLabel("");

private void setAndParseLabel()
{
    dateDataLabel.setText(formatter.format(validatePass.eventDate));

    java.util.Date aDate = formatter.parse(dateDataLabel.getText());
}
```

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`java.text.Format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) does not have method `parse`, so the code does not compile.

You can refer it by [`java.text.DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html):

```
private DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you, a simple oversight on my part.  Much appreciated. I'll accept your answer once the required 10 minutes has passed.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

- You are ignoring crucial issue of time zone. You are unwittingly parsing the input as a value in UTC.
- You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago. Use *java.time* instead.

Example code:

```
LocalDateTime
.parse( 
    "2018-01-23 13:45".replace( " " , "T" )  // Comply with standard ISO 8601 format by replacing SPACE with `T`. Standard formats are used by default in java.time when parsing/generating strings.
)                                            // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object. This is *not* a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.
.atZone(                                     // Apply a time zone to determine a moment, an actual point on the timeline.
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
)                                            // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toInstant()                                 // Adjust from a time zone to UTC, if need be.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

Your input string is almost in standard ISO 8601 format. To fully comply, replace that SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2018-01-23 13:45".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` because your input has no indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

A `LocalDateTime` by definition does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. It represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (the range of time zones around the globe).

To determine a moment, assign a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

If you wish to see that same moment through the wall-clock time of UTC, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from some time zone to UTC.
```

Avoid `java.util.Date` where feasible. But if you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back-and-forth. Call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;  // Going the other direction: `myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()`
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `parse` in `java.text.Format`. Use [`java.text.DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) instead:

```
private DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```